# Cat some specific line which count from bottom of text file

Tags: regex, bash, grep, cat, tail

e.g.

file1:

```
abc
def
ghi
Hi!
xyz
```

file2:

```
111
13215
532
431
2344
Hi!
12fd
```

Expected outputs:

```
$ some_command file1
Hi!
$ some_command file2
Hi!
```

If I want to get `Hi!`, the pattern that I already knew is they are located at the second line of every files (count from bottom). So, the question is how can I get `Hi!` with only information that I have which is `"2"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
tail -n 2 files | head -n 1
```

Explanation :

`tail -n 2` will output the last 2 lines of the input,

And  `| head -n 1` will output the first line of the output from tail.